# How to take iOS log through Appium?

Tags: appium-ios

I tried `--show-IOS-logs` command which is available in appium terminal and started the session. It started working normally but I couldn't find where the logs will be saved. Can someone explain me how to take logs for iOS using appium and how to retrieve it in detail?

Answer (score 0):

you can try with -g or --log option

```
 appium -p 4723 -g appium.log   #This will create a appium log file and will save the logging there
```

Comment: where the appium.log file will be stored in mac?

Comment: You can specify path like /export/home/appium.log

Comment: yea thank you!! that worked fine, but when it comes to Android there is no command like "--show-IOS-logs ", so how can i take Android logs

Comment: I did not get your question, if an android devices are connected it will have android logs!!